# Select combined fields from a Table

Tags: php, mysql

So, right now I have some MySQL and PHP which selects information as shown below:

```
part_number
Part 1
Part 2
Part 3
```

Right now I am using this query:

```
SELECT `part_number`
FROM `quote_items`
WHERE `quote_id` = '$quote_id'
```

I am then using the following PHP to print out the parts in a single field.

```
$j = 0;
foreach($results5 as $result5) {
if($j == 0) {
    echo $result5['part_number'];
} else {
    echo ', '.$result5['part_number'];  
}
    $j = $j + 1;
}
```

How would I get the MySQL to return a result set like this?

```
part_numbers
Part 1, Part 2, Part 3 (This would be a single field of course)
```

Currently I am getting the correct output using my PHP loop, but I would like to select all the information in the correct way from MySQL without using the PHP loop (As I illustrated, I would like to select all the parts separated by commas in one field using MySQL). I guess this would be less code and more effecient.

Comment: what is the output your getting from the above program? Whats the $quote id??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`part_number` SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM `quote_items`
WHERE `quote_id` = '$quote_id';
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop

```
$part_numbers = implode(",", $results5);
echo $part_numbers;
```

Comment: I am receiving the following error now:
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in my_page.php on line 350

Answer (score 0):

Take the result set and implode it:

```
$results5 = implode(', ',$results5);
```